# SAML2.0 With Ping server with C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, ping, saml-2.0

I am new to SAML2 with PING I can't able to find any documents how to implement this one. Is there any step by step documents or examples to implement SAML with C# .Net.

I want to create metadata first. Is there any example how to create metadata for SAML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to act as a service provider and be VERY .Net-centric, then you should either pick a SAML stack like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SAML2/), or, better yet, just go with a commercial SAML stack like [ComponentSpace](https://www.componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net).

Of course, if you are really going to be Ping-specific there is always the [.Net Integration Kit](https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=integrations&topicId=ztk1563995031357.html) that you can review.

I always encourage adoption of Open Source solutions like [Shibboleth](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Home), however, as it's pure SAML middleware and largely agnostic re: what technologies your application uses. So long as you can read server variables or request headers Shibboleth has everything you need to act as an SP.